# Google Scripts If function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a code that creates a new document every time based on the answers to the form. Currently I have 2 different forms and 2 different spread sheets, one for removal and one for addition. I'd like to condense the forms and spreadsheets into one code but I need a 1 or the other question in my form and I can't figure out how to make it chose to do one document or the other based on that answer. I tried the IF function and that is not working. Please help?

This is the code with the if functions. It should create the removal document from the removal template if they answer removing or addition document with additional template if they answer adding

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var removaladdition = e.values[1];
var CustomerName = e.values[2];
var TrustName = e.values[3];
var TrustDate = e.values[4];
var CoTrusteeNames = e.values[5];
var DocLink = e.values[6];

if (removaladdition !== "Adding"){
var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxx");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxx");

var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(CustomerName + ' Appointment Of Co-Trustees', templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText('{{Customer Name}}', CustomerName);
body.replaceText('{{Trust Name}}', TrustName);
body.replaceText('{{Trust Date}}', TrustDate);
body.replaceText('{{Co-Trustee Names}}', CoTrusteeNames);

doc.saveAndClose();}

if (removaladdition !== "Removing"){
var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxx");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxx");

var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(CustomerName + ' Removal Of Co-Trustees', templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText('{{Customer Name}}', CustomerName);
body.replaceText('{{Trust Name}}', TrustName);
body.replaceText('{{Trust Date}}', TrustDate);
body.replaceText('{{Co-Trustee Names}}', CoTrusteeNames);

doc.saveAndClose();}
> }
```

Comment: Check the value of e.values[1],`console.log(e.values[1]);`

Comment: @TheWizEd where should I add this in the script?

Comment: Right after `var removaladdition = e.values[1];`

Comment: I'm not sure why but that did not work. I tried putting it on the same line and it yelled at me so I put it on the next line and that also did not work. I am hitting removing and it is acting like I am hitting adding

Comment: Did you check the execution log?  Also you can not run this from the script editor since `e` is undefined.  It will only work when a form response is submitted.

Comment: @TheWizEd I tested it each time by submitting a form, it does note that I selected removing in the execution but still goes for the addition script

Comment: I removed the ! in front of the == and now it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: Not equal is `!==`, equal is `===` however `!==` and `===` means the variable type is the same and the value is the same.  For example the types are both string or both number and the values of the 2 strings are equal or the values of the 2 numbers are equal.  Some times values of different type can be equal `==` or not equal `!=` such as the number 2 and the string '2'.